# Brackets extensions api

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

my first question here :)

Iam trying to develop a Brackets Extension that would sync all installed extensions across other PCs. Point is, that I can't get info like version, url of the origin repo etc.

I was using ExtensionManager api, but extension field provides only info like following(ex. data for "JSLint" extension:

```
{"installInfo":
    {"metadata":    
        {"name":"JSLint",
        "title":"JSLint"},
    "path":"C:/(...)/default/JSLint",
    "locationType":"default",
    "status":"enabled"}
}
```

I guess that there must be some model extending function, that would attach information I seek.(Brackets for sure has it hidden somewhere, cause native extension manager has all this crucial data - debugging didn't help too much :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out a solution.

```
 ExtensionsManager.downloadRegistry().done(function () {
        for (var k in ExtensionsManager.extensions) {
            if (ExtensionsManager.extensions[k].installInfo && ExtensionsManager.extensions[k].registryInfo) {
FileSystem.resolve(ExtensionsManager.extensions[k].installInfo.path + "/package.json", 
function (err, data) {
                    if (!err) {
                        FileUtils.readAsText(data).done(function (dt) {
                            var lt = JSON.parse(dt);
                            /** -----> **lt** <--------- **/ 
                            // all info about extension is in lt variable
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

some explanations:

**ExtensionManager** is responsible for extensions and information about them, it has a method called ***downloadRegistry***. This method simply populates registry info - intalled addons, addons available to download, native extensions etc.

Method returns a promise, which after resolving, fills extensions attribute of ExtensionsManager, with data required to next step, including names and paths to extensions.

Important part here is, that we have to check if *installInfo* and *registryInfo* attributes are present. Install info extists if addon is installed, registryInfo if its not a native, but downloaded module.

Under *installInfo.path* we can find path to extension folder, by adding "/package.json", we can get main manifest file, with all the extension information - version, repository etc.